# retrieving values from database in java

Tags: java, mysql

I am making a program that retrieves the inputted data/values of fields from the database I created. But when I'm running it the output is always null. I wonder what's wrong? Here's my code:

```
import java.sql.*;

public class GuestsInfo
{
private String  firstName, lastName;
private int  age;
private Connection con;
private PreparedStatement statement;

public GuestsInfo()
{
    try {
         Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
         con = DriverManager.getConnection(
                        "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/3moronsdb","root","");
    } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
public GuestsInfo(String firstName, String lastName, int age)
{
    this();
    try
    {   
        statement = con.prepareStatement("Insert into guest(firstName,lastName,age)values(?,?,?)");

        statement.setString(1, firstName);
        statement.setString(2, lastName);
        statement.setInt(3, age);

        statement.executeUpdate();
        con.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }   
}


public void setFirstName(String firstName)
{

    try{
        statement= con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM guest WHERE firstName = ?");
        statement.setString(1, firstName);
        ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery();
        while(rs.next()){
            firstName = rs.getString(1);
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.print(e);
    }
}

public String getFirstName(){
    return firstName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName)
{

    try{
        statement= con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM guest WHERE lastName = ?");
        statement.setString(2, lastName);
        ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery();
        while(rs.next()){
            lastName = rs.getString(2);
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.print(e);
    }
}

public String getLastName(){
    return lastName;
}

public void setAge(int age){
    try{
        statement = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM guest WHERE age=?");
        statement.setInt(3, age);
        ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery();
        while(rs.next()){
            age = rs.getInt(3);
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.print(e);
    }
}

public int getAge(){
    return age;
}
```

In my main class I have this codes:

```
 public class TestMain {
public static void main(String [] args){

    GuestsInfo gi = new GuestsInfo();
    gi.setFirstName("Ericka");
    System.out.println(gi.getFirstName());

}
 }
```

I wonder why it always says null when I'm running it.

Comment: Ignoring where things are happening, the odds are that you don't have `"Ericka"` stored exactly as a string in your database. It also makes no sense considering you're supplying the value to load. If you know it already, then why would you want to hit the database to load it?

Comment: Looks like your GUESS table doesn't have a row with "Ericka" value in the "firstName" column.

Comment: mm.. actually i already inserted this in my main: GuestsInfo gi = new GuestsInfo("Ericka", "Asi", 18); and I got the datas in my database. What i want is to get the data back from my database. how can I do that?

Comment: @Akcire Atienza See my answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not actually "setting" anything in your setters.

```
public void setFirstName(String firstName)
{

    try{
    // Here you create a READing statement.
        statement= con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM guest WHERE firstName = ?");
        statement.setString(1, firstName);
        ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery();
        while(rs.next()){
    // Here you set the >>method param<< to a non-existing String
            firstName = rs.getString(1);
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
       System.out.print(e);
    }
}
// After the method is done you have done nothing because you didn't even set your class member variable "firstName", which you would have set using "this.firstName".
```

On top of that: My understanding of getters and setter is such that you would do the query in your getter.

Answer (score 0):

You don't appear to be inserting any data in your main method.  Your no arg constructor doesn't create any data.  The setFirstName method uses a select statement so that doesn't do it. Is there a user called Ericka already in the database? Because if not, you've not got any data to return.

I think you meant to use the constructor with multiple args:

```
GuestsInfo gi = new GuestsInfo("Ericka", "Something", 30);
```

Comment: sir actually i inserted this in my main
  GuestsInfo gi = new GuestsInfo("Ericka", "Asi", 18); 
and I got the datas in my database.  What i want is to get the data back from my database. how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

```
GuestsInfo gi = new GuestsInfo();
```

You are not populating your database in your 0-arg constructor... You are just using it to initializing the `connection`.. So, you will not get any data either..

Try creating object by calling your 3-arg constructor..

```
 GuestsInfo gi = new GuestsInfo("Ericka", "lastName", 23);
```

Comment: sir actually i inserted this in my main GuestsInfo gi = new GuestsInfo("Ericka", "Asi", 18); and I got the datas in my database. What i want is to get the data back from my database. how can I do that?

Comment: @AkcireAtienza.. You can't get data out, unless you put data in.. Now to get data, you can try putting correct data in Select query..

Comment: @AkcireAtienza I think this change is enough.. You can try running your code after making the above change.. It will gill give you the output..

Comment: @AkcireAtienza.. Remove `con.close();` this from your 3-arg constructor.. See the end lines of it.. If you close it, you will not be able to connect to database...

Comment: @Rohit in his setter, he used "firstName" as a method param. The class member var is also called "firstName" and thus hidden by the parameter unless he would use "this.firstName" which he did not. So he "sets" the method param.

Comment: @Rohit Thank you sir. I know my error now. I will remember those.

Comment: @Fildor, Thank you sir. I know my error now. I will remember those.